# How to tell what module is running from a function call?

Tags: 7

I wrote a piece of shared code, and I am trying to figure out which module is actually calling the specific function. I am looking to have a mode to turn on debug inside of the shared module if it is being called from a particular module. Also this is in Drupal 7.

To call the shared module, I am using the following to call the function, made generic:

```
module_load_include('inc','rest_api','rest_api');
_rest_api_do_request();
```

Comment: Which function, `_rest_api_do_request`? Based on your include, it's `rest_api` module (file: `rest_api.inc`). Or you're asking something else?

Comment: Some sort of debugger with stack trace could tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the calling function from calling [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). Another way would be to pass it in:

```
_rest_api_do_request(__FUNCTION__);
```

However, either seems like a bad pattern. It's fine for debugging, but a function shouldn't require knowledge of what it is calling it. That's an unnecessary [dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).